# How to add separator line in adminlte menu items

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I'm using Laravel farmwork with AdminLTE. I want to add a separator line after few menu items. For this I tried to add bootstrap's border class in class attribute. I defined the class attribute, which was not there before beneath the url attribute, that is why I think it's not working. Any idea how to achieve a separator line?

This is my adminlte.php file code.

```
            // Sidebar items:
            'text'    => 'Data Entry',
            'icon'    => 'fas fa-fw fa-share',
            'submenu' => [
                [
                    'text' => 'Purchase Invoice',
                    'url'  => 'purchases',
                ],
                [
                    'text' => 'Purchase Return',
                    'url'  => '#',
                ],
                [
                    'text' => 'Company Invoice',
                    'url'  => '#',
                    'class' => 'border-bottom border-dark'
                ],
```

Comment: I think you can find your answer here > https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/issues/1042